# Text highlight when using :hover

Tags: css, hover, highlight

I want to be able to hover over a letter, in this case the 'P' in Paul and have it show up as white, however when i test the site in a web browser, the hover action begins before the mouse touches the actual text.

The picture shows the distance (from the cursor) that it 'hovers' before the actual letter.

[image: distance of hover]

Is there a problem with my code maybe...

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Paul</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div id="pbox"> 
<h2>P</h2><h1>aul</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
body
{
background-color:#4b4b4b;
}

h1
{
font-family:cursive;
font-weight:500;
font-size:50px;
color:silver;
display:inline;
}

h2
{
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:4px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
color:#4b4b4b;
font-family:cursive;
font-weight:600;
font-size:75px;
display:inline;
padding:0px 13px 0px 0px;
}

h2:hover
{
color:#eeeeee;
}

#pbox
{
background-color:white;
width:62px;
height:450px;
top:0px;
left:5px;
border-radius:50px 0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

I will be very grateful if someone could point out my mistakes and find a fix!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I had to guess it probably has to do with your font size. Your letters might 'reserve' some space below the baseline for letters like 'y'.

Comment: @user2793390 This is exactly so. It has nothing to do with line-height.

Comment: I disagree. It does have to do with line-height. If you reduce the line height you can circumvent the problem of the 'space-preservation' no matter what the font-size you're using. So while it may not be attributable to line height, it is fixable with line height. Changing the font-size will help, but only arbitrarily. In particular, a line-height of ~0.7 closes in on the letter pretty squarely.

Comment: @thesublimeobject have you tried adding `line-height`? I got it on a fiddle with no success, no matter what `line-height` is set to: http://jsfiddle.net/gRZFd/

Comment: Apologies. You have to change it to inline-block first instead of just inline for it to effect the element.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider setting your line-height to 1 to make sure there that the element does not extend past the letters themselves. Any padding or extra line-height will cause the problem you're getting. You could even set the padding to less than 1 if you wanted, but it just depends on your desires.

EDIT! -- Switch the h2 to inline-block, not just inline, and then change the line-height to whatever you need. Possibly ~0.7

UPDATED: http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/FjIGD

This uses javascript but basically works perfectly.

Comment: i tried setting it to inline-block, but now the 'aul' is underneath the 'P' and there still seems to be the same distance for hover. :(

Comment: Let me see if I can whip up an example real quick. One minute.

Comment: @ReCeSSiVE I've tried every which way, and I can't get anything to work out exactly like you want it. No matter what I am still getting a little bit of that spacing for the hover, even thought the spacing doesn't actually exist on the element. Here is what I did: http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/FjIGD. I changed some stuff in order to simplify, but you can add you stuff back in, if you would like or use it at all. Sorry that I couldn't get exactly what you wanted.

Comment: that's okay, thank you very much for helping me anyway, i might just have to change my layout and try a different approach, it's a shame that it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's because the pointer is switching to a cursor so that it can highlight, and therefore it seems to enter the hover mode sooner, when possibly what really is happening is the pointer is increasing in size.

Comment: Updated answer. One more try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing line-height style attribute of h2 tag.